# Algorithm in jquery - regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need an algorithm in jquery.

I need an algorithm, for a text field, in which this field of text only allows the insertion of numbers and commas, and between commas does not allow numbers greater than 50.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes i just went through this link which only allows numbers: http://jsfiddle.net/FHf9a/

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
let prevValue = null
$('.numeric').on('input', function(event){
  if(!Array.every(this.value.split(','), (n) => parseInt(n) == n && parseInt(n) <= 50))
    this.value = prevValue
  prevValue = this.value
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0snu052o/